# Como guardar Datos de un Tipo List<> en un archivo .txt?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito hacer una encuesta y guardar los datos de esta en un tipo List<> en un archivo .txt Usando SaveDialog para elegir la ruta de destino. Ya tengo hecho todo lo demás pero aun no logro guardar la lista en el .txt
Alguien sabe como guardar un Tipo List<> en un .txt?

Comment: Aque te referis con guardar un tipo List? vos queres serializar el objeto a disco? no alcanza con que guardes los datos?

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo bien lo que deseas hacer pero para guardar un .txt lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
using(StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/Prueba.txt"), true)){
   escritor.WriteLine("Hola");}
```

Comment: esto no es lo que esta preguntando.. y si mejor esperamos a que aclare su duda?